# Unable to use Then I press the control "name"

Tags: windows-phone-7, wp7test

I am using the WP7test framework from Expensify

But i have an issue with my listbox.

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Labels.MainMenu_Main}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MenuItemSelectedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

When i try using the Then I press the control "someName"

Failed to set focus to control 'someName'

Do anybody know how i can select/press the control?

Comment: Your XAML doesn't show any controls with names defined. Is the code in your question deliberately different from what you have in your actual app? Can you show something which recreates the problem?

Comment: No my code is not deliberately different. But i do not know how to select an item in my ListBox. i could of course use something like "Then I tap on screen x% from the left and y% from the top" but is there some other way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find items individual then you can put an `auto:` Tag value on each individual list item.

e.g.: You could use a list item template like

```
<TextBlock Tag="{Binding AutomationTag}" Text="{Title}" />
```

where AutomationTag resolves to a unique string for each list item like: `auto:1`, `auto:2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to a control by name, you need to give it a name. e.g.:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Labels.MainMenu_Main}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Name="someName" />
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

The ListBox can now be referred to by name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do already know that i can put a name on my listbox. But i can't seem to find anyway to put a name on each item in my listbox. But I have found a solution by making a custom step like this:  [Then(@"I tap the text ""([^\""]*)""$")]        var position = Emu.ApplicationAutomationController.GetPositionOfControlOrText(controlId);    
var gesture = TapGesture.TapOnPosition((int)(position.Left + position.Width / 2),(int)(position.Top + position.Height / 2));     Emu.DisplayInputController.DoGesture(gesture);
}